# C# Comparing 2 strings always return false

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to make the program respond to certain words sent by a microcontroller, but when I compare the received word with a pre-defined word, it always returns false.

```
private void ReadData()
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
    {
        if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            string readBuffer = serialPort1.ReadLine(); 

            textBox2.Text = readBuffer;
            if (readBuffer.Equals("A")) //MY MAIN PROBLEM
            {
                textBox2.Text += "YEP";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text += "NOPE";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically when the microcontroller sends letter "A", it reads it and stores it into the `readBuffer` string, and even prints it out in a `textbox(textBox2)`. My result is always ANOPE in the `textbox` (A is what the microcontroller sent and NOPE is always there because the if failed).
I started C# recently and lost several days trying to figure this one out, but I really can't seem to find a solution to an apparently simple issue.

Comment: Perhaps the new line is included in the `readBuffer` string?

Comment: Have you debugged this? Maybe there is a `\n` or some other byte after the `A` in the string. You did a `ReadLine` so there may be some new line character that your text box does not display.

Comment: Could be an "A" in a different encoding (Cyrillic?)

Comment: Also try `readBuffer.StartsWith("A")`

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly fast replies! And yes, it did add a carriage return (\r) after the A, which I couldn't see, but the debbuger caught it!

Comment: Usually it helps to view quoted version in output or debugger, like "[" + x + "]".

Comment: Also, look "nearby."  BytesToRead was probably "2" in the debugger.  That should raise the question, "What's the second byte?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Willem Van Onsem and René Vogt I figured out the problem.
After it reads the data and stores it into the readBuffer, it also includes \r (carriage return), making the string actually "A\r", which is why it was always false compared to "A".

Comment: set `serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n"` and then `ReadLine()` will nolonger return the `\r`

Answer (score 0):

Two things I submit to you:
**1. Things are not always as they appear:**
use readBuffer.Trim().Equals("A") instead.

2. **readBuffer.Equals("A") performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.** 
   A = A but A ≠ a if you use .Equals to compare them.

So in final analysis, try this:
***if (readBuffer.Trim().ToUpper().Equals("A"))***